# How to set new window position to default in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

My new window always shifts into task bar (see image).

How do I fix it?

Resolution:FULL HD, Task bar size:52

[image]

Answer (score 10):

use compiz config setting manager to adjust it. in window management->place windows->placement mode->smart or center, and then enable place windown. My system version is ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This actually solves the issue for me. Thank you! :) But do you know what might cause the issue so that we've got to install and use compizconfig to adjust this?

Comment: Enabling this "Window Management -> Place Windows" plugin in Compiz works very good for me. 
As it it seems to me, installing Compiz does the "Window Management -> Place Windows" plugin _not enable by default_, so Compiz replaces the former window manager "placing logic" by "no place logic".

Answer (score 2):

My system: 16.04, Mate edition.

Using ccsm, in my case, didnt work. Most apps would still open @ upper left. Few were all over the place, no rhyme/reason.

What did work 100%, was going setting:
control-center -> look and feel -> windows -> placement -> center

What a relief. My monitor is 49" 4K :), was getting serious neck sprain just having to look all the way up and drag the windows down into better position.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 Unity, use the Onboard Settings utility - Window, Docking 
 - UNcheck Dock to Screen Edge